# How to access this.state.someProperty in a React container but outside the class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a React container. Is there a way to observe the current value of `this.state.someProperty` from outside the class?

I have a validate utility function, part of redux-form, in which I want to reference `this.state.someProperty`, but I don't know how to observe the current state.

```
class SomeContainer extends Component {
    something() {
        this.setState({ someProperty: true })
    }
    render() {
        // this.state.someProperty works here
    }
}

// How do I observe the current state of
// this.state.someProperty inside validate() ?
const validate = (formProps) => {
    if (!this.state.someProperty) {
        errors.someField = 'Special message.'
    }
}

export default reduxForm({
    validate,
    form: 'SomeForm',
    fields: ['a', 'b', 'someField']
}, null, actions)(SomeContainer)
```

Normally, I would do something like pass the state into the validate function, but redux-form is controlling its execution.

What is the recommended approach here?

Comment: I basically need a solution that doesn't involve the `this` keyword. I don't mind passing the entire state object into the validate function, if that can be viable. It's just a load testing GUI for a 40 microservice API.

Comment: Do the two components have a child or parent relationship?

Comment: One is just a function written inside the JS file but outside the class.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're writing the function outside of the class? I don't think React can control anything that's not in a component.

Comment: I mostly want to know what it would take to make it possible. It's not critical or anything. This function was just sitting outside there as its simply a utility function that takes an input object and populates an error object. It should look familiar to those familiar with `redux-form`. I am more so functional paradigm from node.js, so I am secretly probing to find every opportunity to stay away from inheritance and `this` keyword. This app is just for load testing an API, but I am interested in anti-patterns. This is an example where I cannot simply write a function to do what I want.

Comment: You can see at the bottom of my example, the function is called validate and you can see it loaded into `reduxForm()`, so I can't even add a parameter to it because its executed by redux-form on keypress. I'd like to know what is physically possible in these conditions, such as `import state from '../app'` or something like that.

Comment: My solution was actually to just remove the property to make the error slightly ambiguous rather than exactly correct :) I'd like to hear any input, however.